# How to make Include specific field in IList in MongoDbDriver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq

I want to understand how I can make Include a specific field from List in MongoDBdriver (any solutions)

When i try to Include some property
For example:

```
  var projection = Builders <SomeClass> .Projection
  .Include (x => x.Id)
```

Its works without any problems.

But when i tryed to include a specific field from a sheet

```
 var projection = Builders <SomeClass> .Projection
.Include (x => x.ListOfSomeClasses.Select (x => x.SomeProperty))
```

I get this exception

```
  Error occurred during request execution
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.ListOfSomeClasses.Select (x => x.SomeProperty).
```

Before that, I worked with postgres and there were no such problems there.

Perhaps there are some problems in Mongo with this. Any answers very helps me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# driver allows using a raw MQL for LINQ queries that are not supported in typed way:

```
var projection = Builders<SomeClass>.Projection
   .Include("ListOfSomeClasses.SomeProperty");
```

Comment: you god! how I didnt think about it..

Comment: if it helped, please mark question as resolved to reduce attention to it